# cUrl not working in PHP

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to have a php script that displays a url with user data in it. The script is shown as follows.

```
<?php 
$url = "localhost/" + $_GET['type'] + "/" + str_replace(' ','%20',$_GET['message']) + "/";
print $url;
// create curl resource 
$ch = curl_init(); 
// set url 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 6677); 
//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
// close curl resource to free up sylstem resources 
curl_close($ch);

if ($output) { 
print $output;
}
else
{
print 'FAILED';
}
?>
```

This is part of a game that I am trying to make where the people talk using [A.L.I.C.E](http://alicebot.blogspot.com/), written in AIML (Artificial Intellagence Markup Language). I am using [PyAIML](http://pyaiml.sourceforge.net/). It needs to connect to a Python server on a different port.

The says when a request is received and it does not say it is getting a request at the when I load the page. I used tamper data to remove **ALL** request headers and it still worked with Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your first line. You're using the numeric addition operator `+` when you want to use the string concatenation operator instead `.`

Before:

```
$url = "localhost/" + $_GET['type'] + "/" + str_replace(' ','%20',$_GET['message']) + "/";
```

After:

```
$url = "http://localhost/" . $_GET['type'] . "/" . str_replace(' ','%20',$_GET['message']) . "/";
```

Also, note it couldn't hurt to explicitly declare the protocol portion of the URL.

Comment: Thanks. I program mainly javascript so I often forget this.